# Does double wrapping food work for non-kosher food?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, cooking-bishul

I have read several articles stating that one may double wrap food and place it into a non-kosher oven.

I haven't read anything regarding the "opposite situation". Lets say one has verified that an oven owned by a non-Jew had all non-kosher food double-wrapped. Can a Jew place kosher food that is **un**wrapped into that oven?

It seems to me that this would be OK, but are there any other possible concerns, here?

Answer (score 3):

The *halachot* of an oven are much more lenient that one of a dish, since there is no contact between the food and the oven. The real issues are regarding the oven tray which touches the food or dish and transmits taste - and possibly any recent projections of (non-kosher) food on the walls.

As such a clean oven not used for 24 hours, or having undergone pyrolysis (self-cleaning), can be used to cook kosher food if the oven tray is covered (e.g., with aluminium foil).

Your case is even simpler, it is like one of a new oven and there is no issue cooking unwrapped kosher food in there.

Source: I spent the last months learning these *halachot* with a *rosh kollel* from Bnei Brak and checked again a similar case last week.