# What are the "maasim tovim"?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, torah-study, chesed-kindness

Talmud, mishna, and other sources reference "maasim tovim" (good deeds) in many places (Avos 4:17 is one example). Do any sources define what this term actually includes?

Some of the possible options are:

1. Does it include only specific mitzvos to the exclusion of others (for example, only mitzvos ben adam lechavero vs. ben adam leMakom?)
2. Perhaps it includes general good deeds that are not categorized under any of the 613 mitzvos?
3. Perhaps it is an all-encompasing synonym for all 613 mitzvos? How would this mesh with the fact that the common expression "leTorah...uleMaasim Tovim" appears to exclude learning Torah from "maasim tovim?"

Comment: Surmising - "ma'asim tovim" maybe referring specifically to mitzvoth that assist other people such as charity, and other ways that positively affect others.

Comment: @DanF - what is the basis for your idea? What makes charity more of a good deed than taking lulav, for example?

Comment: I'm not comparing on any hierarchy. I'm just surmising that the term "deed", to me, means something that affects others.

Comment: @DanF - I believe "deed" just means any performed action.

Comment: Not an answer, but, perhaps, something to ponder? https://divreichaim.blogspot.com/2007/08/torah-chuppah-maasim-tovim-why-good.html

Answer (score -1):

I asked my rav, and he confirmed my analysis.

Often "ma'asim tovim" is synonymous with the term "mitzvah". However, he's inclined to think that the term "mitzvah" is generic and includes commandments that we **must** do because G-d commanded them such as eating kosher, observing Shabbat, etc. It includes commandments that are both between man and G-d as well as those between man and neighbor.

"Ma'asim Tovim", the rav feels, refers only to deeds between man and his neighbor that go above and beyond what the Torah commands. For example, the Torah does not command visiting the sick. Doing so is a "mitzvah" (offhand, not sure which ones) but it would also be considered a "good deed" (ma'aseh tov.)

Comment: What is the textual source or rationale behind this explanation? I don't think visiting the sick example helps your explanation, as many rishonim (Ramban, Rabbeinu Yonah, Tzitz Eliezer, etc.) classify visiting the sick as a biblical mitzvah. It is even codified in Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah 335:1.

Comment: I will have to look at the source in Yoreh Deah. I implicitly trust my rav's knowledge, so he doesn't have to back up his comments with a source as far as I am concerned. Of course, he's human and can make mistakes, as anyone else does. I'll see if I can print that source and ask him about that. He mentioned *bikur cholim* as an example, and, apparently, it may not be the best one, here. I still don't think it detracts from his general interpretation, though.

Comment: My understanding of this site is that an answer needs to have either a documented source or a logical explanation. Answers based on anonymous rebbeim don't really help. Am I wrong on this?

Comment: You're not completely wrong. I'll see if I can get additional info. May take some time. Your question is a great one. Sometimes, it's just hard to find answers to good questions. I have a number of these, myself.

Comment: Incidentally, someone answered one of my questions, yesterday using an anonymous rav as a source - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/106100/5275. I am fine with this answer. We have had many "anonymous rav" answers. There are many non-anomymous rabbanim cited as sources on this site whom I have not heard of. Even if I were to name my rav, you wouldn't have heard of him, anyway. so I doubt that would alter your confidence. I agree that a written source is better as you can research it further. But, as I've stated, I implicitly trust any rav's word - my own or others.

Comment: The answer is XYZ because an anonymous rav feels so?

Comment: I'm really not here to debate our level of *Emunat Chachamim*, Tesvov. That's, essentially, what your last comment / question implies. I expended some effort to relay your question to my rav, that's all. Whether you like his answer or not is fine with me, either way.